# Can't find on action of controller in ASP.NET MVC4 - HTTP 404 error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, post

One of my POST actions is throwing HTTP 404 error. I've been at it for last couple of hours and have no idea what's wrong! All other actions in the same controller work just fine. I'm pretty sure spellings are correct. When in debug mode, this method is never hit (well, obviously I guess). Please help.

Here's the action method -

```
public class LookupTableController : Controller
{
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AjaxLookupTableCRUDDelete(int lookupId)
    {
        LookupTable lookuptable = db.LookupTables.Find(lookupId);
        if (lookuptable != null)
        {
            db.LookupTables.Remove(lookuptable);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        return Index();
    }
```

No matter how I try to access it, it throws the 404 error!

I tried directly on the browser - `http://localhost:60328/LookupTable/AjaxLookupTableCRUDDelete/?lookupId=111` ,

It shows -

```
>Server Error in '/' Application.
```

> The resource cannot be found.
>   Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its >dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily >unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled >correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /LookupTable/AjaxLookupTableCRUDDelete/

Fiddler -

> Headers - POST /LookupTable/AjaxLookupTableCRUDDelete?lookupId=13 HTTP/1.1 
>   `[HttpException]: A public action method &#39;AjaxLookupTableCRUDDelete&#39; was >not found on controller &#39;GBPReconTool.Controllers.LookupTableController&#39;.`

Routing is standard -

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

**Resolved - Thanks guys, it turned out to be the GET vs POST problem.** - When I first compiled it, it did not have a HTTPGet or HTTPPost attribute. I'm not sure how ASP.NET MVC4 determines what it is supposed to be. In any case, explicit POST ajax calls to that failed and started testing it directly in the browser. The browser was apparently posting it as a GET. I'm still not clear on how this is determined but I guess adding the HTTPPost attribute to the controller is what finally fixed it. Guess I'll be reading up on how ASP.NET and browsers determine whether an action is GET or POST.

Comment: try a quick test: change this action to accept GET verb, and try to reach this action through querystring: http://localhost:60328/LookupTable/AjaxLookupTableCRUDDelete?lookupId=111 ,

Comment: @Thiago Custodio - I just tried changing to GET. Now it's saying This is what shows up when I change the action to GET instead -"The view 'AjaxLookupTableCRUDDelete' or its master was not found or no view >engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:..."

Answer (score 0):

Try using this ...

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AjaxLookupTableCRUDDelete(int id)
{
    LookupTable lookuptable = db.LookupTables.Find(id);
    if (lookuptable != null)
    {
        db.LookupTables.Remove(lookuptable);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    return Index();
}
```

then try using ...

```
POST http://localhost:60328/LookupTable/AjaxLookupTableCRUDDelete/111
```

As others have stated, you need to make sure that the request is being sent as a POST.

Another thing you might want to check is that ContentType is set correctly in Fiddler.

```
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
```

Comment: Just tried it like that as well. Throwing the same error -  The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /LookupTable/AjaxLookupTableCRUDDelete/111

Comment: Any chance you could provide a screenshot of the Fiddler POST that you're sending?

Answer (score 0):

change the action signature to the following:

```
    public ActionResult AjaxLookupTableCRUDDelete(int? id)
    {
    }
```

The idea here is to have the action variable name match what you already have in your routes.

the POST url will need to look like this:

```
    http://localhost:60328/LookupTable/AjaxLookupTableCRUDDelete/111
```

you don't need to supply the variable name since mvc will gleam it from the url based on your route

Comment: "POST url"? Maybe I'm missing something here, but how are you passing parameters in the url and expecting a POST to work?

Comment: @ShaiCohen asp.net mvc will pull the parameter from the uri. you don't need to have a form body to post.

Answer (score 0):

I know this sounds simple but:

- Make sure you saved the class file
- Make sure you built the project

Then use Chrome or FireFox development tools (F12) and look at the Network tab. You can get a look at the actual url and type (POST, GET) that is being passed to your application. You will also see any querystring parameters and form data as well.

Generally if there's something wrong it will become apparent by this point.

FYI - You can also use Fiddler2 to get a look at the actual http request as well.